# showing navigation after set width in jquery

Tags: jquery, navigation, media-queries

I'm trying to build my own responsive navigation menu, I'm doing mobile first then up. The menu works great upto my set media width 40em's, then I can't see the menu after that. What I need help with is to drop the function at a set width so i can simply code the rest in css or use a if else statement that says if max-width 40em (hide), else (show).

This works upto 40em or 641px

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".navbar").hide();
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(".navbar").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: :can you share the fiddle

Comment: Here's the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BL3nj/) you'll need to srink the screen to see it, also i'm using less so some of the styles are missing. Doesn't show well in fiddle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add the window resize function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 1024){  
        $(".navbar").hide();
    }   else {
        $(".navbar").show();
    }
});
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(".navbar").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```